# bash script returns error "ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: SELECT" for psql request to copy the table to an external file

Tags: macos, bash, select, psql

What should I do for making it work?

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLENAMES="user_stats"
ssh -t railsapps@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p xxx bash -c "'

for TABLENAME in $TABLENAMES
do
    psql -d mydb -P format=unaligned -P tuples_only -P fieldsep=\, -c "SELECT * FROM $TABLENAME" > /tmp/$TABLENAME  
done
'"
```

General problem: how to periodically dump the database tables to a local machine from a psql database in a single bash script run on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should test your SQL and bash scripts remotely (do SSH interactively).

I think your problem is caused by a bad mix of quote / double-quote. I think the star `(*)` and `$TABLENAME` are expensed before the SSH call, so too early. Try to put a backslash before the `$` sign.

You should use the verbose or the debug option, to help to understand what is really executed:

```
ssh -t railsapps@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p xxx bash -vxc "'
for TABLENAME in \$TABLENAMES; do
    psql -d mydb -P format=unaligned -P tuples_only -P fieldsep=\, -c "SELECT \* FROM \$TABLENAME" > /tmp/\$TABLENAME  
done
'"
```